# MYSQL RANDOM SELECT UNIQUE ROWS - Excluding previously selected rows

Tags: php, mysql, random, unique

I have a table of 16K entries
I want to extract random 44 entries
but I don't want to repeat the same entries more then once (ever)
so i have a per-user list that keeps the already used 'IDs' as a comma-separated string in a table.
and I use that list to SELECT ... NOT IN (used_IDs)

The issue is that this list is getting too big and the sql call fails because of size i believe

Any idea on how to do that more usefully?

```
Questions table:
+------+-------+-------+
| id   | Qtext | Tags  |
+------+-------+-------+

Test table:
+------+-------+
| id   | QIDs  |
+------+-------+

Results table:
+------+-------+-------+
| id   | tID   | uID   |
+------+-------+-------+
```

I need to select unique random values from Questions table based on the results table. (which associates test ID with Question IDs)

Currently trying to use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `questions`.`ID`
FROM `questions`, `tests`, `results`
WHERE 
`questions`.`ID` NOT IN (`tests`.`qIDs`)
AND `results`.`uID` = 1 AND `tests`.`ID` = `results`.`tID`
AND 4 IN ( `questions`.`tags`) 
AND "http://www.usmlestep2qna.com" = `provider`
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 27;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: 16K records is not really a very big table by most enterprise standards. Can you share the table structure and the query plan for your query? There may be some optimization possible in the current approach itself..

Comment: Based on your discussion with Andrew below, thats a good way to start with the optimization. In addition, once u do that, in the above query you should look to replace the cross joins you have between `questions`, `tests` and `results` table with `inner join` instead. Best way will be to do an `EXPLAIN <your query>` - then analyze the query plan and optimize accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of placing the used user Id values in a comma-separated string in one column, you could create a tall table to store them. This should yield better preformance

Comment: I'm not sure that having a table of 16K rows for each user is better then just storing it in a strings - is it?

Comment: Yes, because a table can be indexed.

Comment: You don't need 16K rows for each user. Each time you select IDs, you add just 44 rows to the table.

Comment: yeah but these users are going to create lots of tests, these might stack up to more then 16K rows each... but the indexing part you've mentioned sounds good...

Comment: Also with the where clause it should be pretty speedy. Select Random Id's from GoodTable - UsedTable where userId = @userId

Comment: You're going to be storing just as much data by making a long string. It will be even more, because you're converting it to text instead of storing it as integers. And when you're doing the NOT IN, it has to parse all the strings back to numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using a single row with a (potentially huge) CSV, why not use a nicely indexed table and an outer join to pick unmatched records. I have an example from my test database:

```
mysql> select * from first;
+------+-------+
| id   | title |
+------+-------+
|    1 | aaaa  |
|    2 | bbbb  |
|    3 | cccc  |
|    4 | NULL  |
|    6 | gggg  |
+------+-------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from second;
+------+----------+------+------+-------+------+
| id   | first_id | one  | two  | three | four |
+------+----------+------+------+-------+------+
|    1 |        1 |    3 |    0 |     4 |    6 |
|    1 |        2 |    4 |    4 |     1 |    2 |
|    3 |        3 |    1 | NULL |     3 |    4 |
+------+----------+------+------+-------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select a.id from first a join second b on a.id=b.first_id;
+------+
| id   |
+------+
|    1 |
|    2 |
|    3 |
+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select a.id from first a 
left outer join second b on a.id=b.first_id where b.first_id is null;
+------+
| id   |
+------+
|    4 |
|    6 |
+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

This should improve your performance rather nicely.